# Greeting activity for android app

Tags: android

i'd like a way to make a greeting activity launching before the mainActity start , it's kind of welcome screen for the app for example ( logo or image )

Comment: The question is quite clear and specific, and has answers which should be a good starting point.  Note however that what happens (or should happen) upon re-entry to the application after the user has gone to a different one may get interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);    
        Thread splash= new Thread(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
            };
            splash.start();

    }
```

exactly what you need! modify according to your needs

Answer (score 1):

You just create new activity and then move this code in the manifest to be attached to your new activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the activity just display the icon you want and then use [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to countdown until you take the user to another activity using intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem? Just make an Activity with the greeting and then launch your MainActivity after some elapsed time